# iOS autolayout add constraint outside the parent view

Tags: ios, ios8, autolayout, ios9, xcode7

Can anyone help me to understand how to add constraint outside the parent view

--ContentView 

----**UIImageView1** 

----View

-------**UIImageView2**

I want to have the same height of the **UIImageView1** and **UIImageView2**

Answer (score 1):

You need to Add Equal Height , and Aspect Ratio Constraint to Imageview 2  corrosponding to Imageview 1.

[image]

Note :- If your Height of Both imageview fix then Just give Fix Height to Both Imageview.

[image]

Comment: shal one help how you are getting video shot like this

Comment: @KishoreKumar use Gyzo like application. https://gyazo.com/